# C# Dictionary Index was outside the bounds of the array with lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, locking

I have this code:

```
lock (dict)
{
    dict.Add(someKey, someValue);
    Task task = new Task (() => doSomething);
    task.Start();
    task.ContinueWith(() => {dict.Remove(someKey);});
}
```

Since I already have a lock on dict, why do I still get the error

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

I can't reproduce the error, but another person did.

Comment: Lock is released with good probabilities immediately after you started your task, to read as: code inside task is not thread-safe in respect of dict. Even if they were synchronous...lock works per-thread. Moreover why do you start the task and then add continuation instead of vice-versa? Final note: IndexOutOfRangeException is completely unrelated to Dictionary then it comes from something else

Comment: Hi Adriano, from the stack trace, the exception comes from dict.Add(), which is why I believe it has to do with Dictionary.

Comment: Show us stack trace! Add() _may_ throw it if dictionary is updated concurrently but from code you posted it's simply synchronous (unless you repeatedly call that block of code, in that case yes, there is a race with dict.Remove()). Anyway, solution is to lock when you remove (as an answer now deleted shown)

Comment: Yes, that block of code in in a foreach loop, I will post the stack trace shortly.

Comment: That's enough, it may happen when dictionary updates its buckets (between when it computes index for bucket array and when it accesses that array, if an element is removed between those two steps then you get an index out of range if it was last one - or invalid results for the others). Just do: lock { dict.Remove(); }

Comment: lock { dict.Remove(); } isn't working for me. It is expecting round brackets after the lock. Should I do lock (dict) { dict.Remove(); } ?

Answer (score 2):

`dict.Remove(someKey);` does not run inside of the lock. It runs on a different thread. This code is not properly synchronized.

Probably, what you need is `lock (dick) dict.Remove(someKey);`. Then, the dictionary will behave correctly. The `Add` and the `Remove` will not be one atomic operation, however.